# Sync coredata with restkit

Tags: core-data, restkit

Ti have a ready-to-sell app with coredata. Now i need to synch my data with a restfull webservice.
I tried restkit framework, but in first examples restkit make is own coredata stack, and i'm forced to use "Active Record" to find my objects with methods like findAll: or findAllWithPredicate:.

There is a way for reuse my code and use restkit only for sync process?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestKit will work with your existing core data model. You aren't forced to use the active record additions at all - feel free to ignore it.

As to your question. Before you try and fix everything by using RestKit. I recommend understanding exactly what you are trying to achieve with this "sync process". In fact RestKit does not magically sync anything (although there was that branch somewhere...). If you do not understand synchronization first, you will not be able to develop this system well.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I read some posts about synchronization, and i write my specs using "last_update" way.
I know that maybe this isn't best approach, but it works in my scenario.
I will try to use restkit without active record, i think is a good framework.... although it hasn't any magical solution for sync.